# Error 500 on GAE local dev server with Laravel and PHP 5.5

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel

I'm running Laravel on Google App Engine.

Since App Engine runs PHP using a PHP 5.5 interpreter, I specified php55 as runtime. The project runs well on Google's servers.

When I run my website on the local dev server the SDK provides using runtime: php everything works fine. Changing the runtime to php55 gives me a blank page and the following error in my log:

```
Unable to delete function dlUnable to delete function mb_send_mail
ERROR:root:php failure (255) with:
stdout:
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.23
Content-type: text/html
```

I installed the newest version of the GAE SDK.

Of course I can run with the runtime variable set to php instead of php55, but I'm still wondering why runtime: php55 doesn't work on localhost and if I'm missing something here.

Comment: Are you running it on Linux using command line? Or using the launcher on Windows or Mac?

Comment: I'm using the launcher on Mac

Comment: Have you tried turning on debug mode by setting APP_DEBUG environmental variable in your app.yaml?

Comment: APP_DEBUG is set to true in my Laravel .env. Is there a similar variable I can set in app.yaml? I found a discussion here with people getting the same [Unable to delete function dlUnable to delete function mb_send_mail] error: https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds/issues/26

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/laravel?

Comment: I've never seen that repository, thanks for sharing. Currently I'm using https://github.com/shpasser/GaeSupportL5 to get my projects running in production.

Comment: The GoogleCloudPlatform/laraval repository runs fine on the local dev server, also with php55. I don't get the error anymore in my initial project too, running with php55. Could it be possible that one of the required dependencies for the Laravel Starter app has global effects and solved the issue?

Comment: Glad that it works. If you're interested the exact changes I made, take a look at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/laravel/commit/495181b64dab9ce8ac22fb957b859c35181a010b

Comment: @Mars - You may want to open a ticket here: https://github.com/shpasser/GaeSupportL5 - this is the package I'm currently using.  It's a slightly nicer way to encapsulate the setup, without taking a hard dependency on GAE.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this as well on OSX running via command line. My suspicion is that this is a bug in the Google App Engine development server.

I've opened a ticket here and will gladly update this answer once something more concrete is determined:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12127